# Excel conditional formatting formula not working

Tags: excel

I Have a column of numbers C3 to C20 in EXCEL: -0.08, -.07, -.06,...., 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 .... 0.08
$C$1 = .03

I tested my formula =ABS(C3)>$C$1. It gives the correct TRUE and FALSE
but when I use the formula in conditional formatting and apply it to row $C$3:$C20.
it does not work. What am I doing wrong? this is very similar to some basic examples given in tutorials.

the conditional formatting with formula seems to work if I use a formula like =ISODD(ROW()) (which was given in a tutorial). So the conditional formatting is working in that particular case

However I cannot get my formula above to work. I can't figure out why. This is a very simple case. I cannot get it to work even if I use an even simpler  formula like =C3>$C$1

Can you help? is there something basic I cannot see or some setting in EXCEL that need to be changed? is it my version of EXCEL that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works:
[image: sample excel file]

with this condition:

```
=ABS($A1) > $A$1
```

The `$` in `ABS` is optional to prevent any expansion by columns, because you want to apply the rule only to column `A`.

You can change the value **Apply to range** to include the entire column as follow: `A:A`. For this condition doesn't matter, but there are situations where you want to apply the rule only for non empty rows, in such case you can change the above formula as follow:

```
=AND(LEN($A1)>0, ABS($A1) > $A$1)
```

Comment: Thank you.I fixed the problem. It was that for some reason, my version of Excel did not recognise the formula (even a simple formula =C3>$C$1) like  as a formula and automatically put "" on either side of the formula in the dialog box. If I go back and edit manually and take the "" out, all my  formula based formula conditional formatting works fine. Thank you for taking the time to try and help. not sure why excel does that.